# How to get all elements of a matrix except its first element, in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix

To find the output of the following formula in Matlab, I need to get all elements of a matrix (`PDA` in the following code) except its first element without using any loop.

Formula(Goal): `% EVec = (A11-B11).^2 - (A12-B12).^2 - .. - (Aij-Bij).^2`

Ex:

```
A(:,:,1) = [1 2 3 4; 4 5 6 1]; 
A(:,:,2) = [0 5 4 3; 2 7 6 0];
A(:,:,3) = [1 2 3 9; 0 6 7 0];

B(:,:,1) = [4 0 3 4; 4 8 0 1];
B(:,:,2) = [0 5 6 1; 0 9 4 3];
B(:,:,3) = [2 0 3 5; 8 6 7 2];

PDA = (A-B).^2;
EVec = PDA(1,1,:) - sum(PDA(?, ?, :)); % The problem is sum(PDA(?, ?,:)).
```

The result of PDA is:

```
PDA(:,:,1) =

     9     4     0     0
     0     9    36     0

                               % All of them except Val(1,1) = 9.
PDA(:,:,2) =

     0     0     4     4
     4     4     4     9

                               % All of them except Val(1,1) = 0.
PDA(:,:,3) =

     1     4     0    16
    64     0     0     4
                               % All of them except Val(1,1) = 1.
```

And my problem is in the output of `PDA(1,1,:) - sum(PDA(?, ?, :))` that should be:`9-(4+0+0+0+0+9+36+0), 0-(0+4+4+4+4+4+9), 1-(4+0+16+64+0+0+4) = [-40, -29, -87].`.Unfortunately it doesn't.

How to get all elements of a matrix except its first element in Matlab?

Comment: The sum of all elements minus the first element: `sum(A(:))-A(1)`. But you have to do something slightly different because you don’t want to sum across the 3rd dimension.

Comment: @Cris Luengo: No, I want: 9-(4+0+0+0+0+9+36+0), 0-(0+4+4+4+4+4+9), 1-(4+0+16+64+0+0+4).  So, how to get (4+0+0+0+0+9+36+0) in PDA(:,:,1) and etc, without the loop?

Comment: Please add the exact desired output in the question

Comment: I think we’re saying the same thing. The sum of all but the first element is the same as the sum of all elements minus the first element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first element minus the sum of the remaining elements is just twice the first element minus the sum of all elements, so

```
>> squeeze(2*PDA(1,1,:) - sum(sum(PDA,1),2))
ans =
   -40
   -29
   -87
```

Or in newer releases

```
>> squeeze(2*PDA(1,1,:) - sum(PDA,[1,2]))
ans =
   -40
   -29
   -87
```